# Access Report - Calculating Hours between 2 times

Tags: ms-access, time, report

I have a SQL time off database with a Access front end.  I currently have BeginTimeOff and EndTimeOff fields on the report.  In my SQL database, these are Time(7) fields.  I want a new field to show the time difference.  I've tried to have the Control Source be equal to:

```
=DateDiff("n",CDate([BeginTimeOff]),CDate([EndTimeOff]))
```

AND

```
=DateDiff("n",[BeginTimeOff],[EndTimeOff])
```

AND

```
= [EndTimeOff] - [BeginTimeOff]
```

I can't get anything to work.  I can subtract dates fine, just not times.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access does not have a time-only field type (Access `Date/Time` fields have both a date and time component), and any unknown field types in an ODBC linked table are usually mapped to `Text`. So if you have a SQL Server table with `time(7)` columns ...

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeTest](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BeginTimeOff] [time](7) NULL,
    [EndTimeOff] [time](7) NULL
    ...
```

then the corresponding ODBC linked table in Access will have `Text(255)` columns instead:

[image: AccessTable.png]

If you want to directly use the columns in the linked table then you will have to convert the values into a form that Access will accept before you can use functions like `DateDiff()` to do calculations with them. Specifically, Access Date/Time values do not support fractional seconds so you will have to remove them. That is,

```vbs
CDate("07:59:00.0000000")
```

will fail with a "Type mismatch" error (run-time error 13), while

```vbs
CDate("07:59:00")
```

works fine. You can use string manipulation functions like `InStr()`, `Left()`, `Mid()`, etc. to get rid of the fractional part of the string.

Another approach would be to create a SQL Server View that converts the `DATE(7)` columns to `DATETIME`

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TimeView]
AS
SELECT
    Id, 
    DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(DATETIME, BeginTimeOff)) AS BeginTimeOff, 
    DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(DATETIME, EndTimeOff)) AS EndTimeOff
FROM dbo.TimeTest
```

and then if you link to that View the columns will appear as `Date/Time` values in Access

[image: LinkedView.png]

Comment: But then `=DateDiff("n",CDate([BeginTimeOff]),CDate([EndTimeOff]))` shouldn't fail. We need more info.

Comment: OK. Then `=DateDiff("n",CDate(Left([BeginTimeOff],8)),CDate(Left([EndTimeOff],8)))` should work.